# Address Book in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I am having trouble working with address book in my current app. The app should be able to let user delete and restore deleted contacts.

to restore contacts, i m thinking to save a copy of vCard to each "person" object, using archives and NSCoding methods, and save it to disk. that way i can pull the "person" object graph out with vCard as a NSData property.

and my question is since vCard doesn't support NSCoding, is it possible to wrap vCard into NSData and use it in encode and decode method in NSCoding protocol?

thanks guys!

Comment: vCard is just a data format, so yes, you can save it in NSData. I don't know what you're building, but a better route might be to use the users's exiting address book via the AddressBook.framework.